# Major sets and their algebra, operations

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

There are many major sets of numbers which have definitions we are all familiar with. For example, the set $\mathbb{Z}$ contains a countable number of elements which are given the labels $\dots,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,\dots$ etc.

When we talk about this set, we assume that there are particular operators defined on the set (among others):
$$\begin{align}+&:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}
\\
\cdot\:&:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\end{align}$$
Such that $(\mathbb{Z},+,\,\cdot\,)$ defines a particular commutative ring where $0$ and $1$ are the additive and multiplicative identities respectively.

My question is this: are these operations inherently defined somewhere within the set's definition, or is the algebra of the set merely *implied*?

My understanding was that a set consisted solely of a series of elements which we label with whatever names we want. Any algebra on the set, including operations such as $+$, $\cdot$ and exponentiation would then defined in addition to the set itself. Is this done using relations on the set?

Comment: See e.g. Herbert Enderton, [Elements of Set Theory](http://www.amazon.com/Elements-Set-Theory-Herbert-Enderton/dp/0122384407/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1402909449&sr=8-1&keywords=Herbert+Enderton+Elements+of+Set+Theory) (1977); page 66 for the *set-theoretic* definition of *natural numbers*. Page 79-on for *Arithmetic* (definition of operations between natural numbers : $+, \cdot$); page 90 for the definition of *integers* and page 92 for the definition of operation between integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operations on something like the integers are not what you'd call inherently defined; we can ignore them entirely and treat $\mathbb{Z}$ as an arbitrary countable set; or we can take any arbitrary countable set, fix a bijection, and use that bijection to "transfer" the operations over, creating an algebraic structure indistinguishable from $\mathbb{Z}$.

That said, some sets are certainly more amenable than others to *defining* the desired operations. Instantiating $\mathbb{Z}$ as a quotient of $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$, for instance, makes it fairly easy to find set theoretic formulae that define the algebraic operations by using the operations on $\mathbb{N}$. While it's true that we can equip any countable set with an isomorphic ring structure, the extra information about the underlying sets of our usual constructions is what helps us show nicely that we have such a ring structure on some countable set in the first place.

Comment: Let me see if I understand: the operations we have on $\mathbb{Z}$ are essentially inherited from its construction via $\mathbb{N}$. We construct it this way because it is the easiest, most inuitive way to obtain a commutative ring with a countable number of elements. It also means that any properties discovered in the future about $\mathbb{N}$ might be inherited. We desire such a ring because it is useful in other fields of mathematics and life in general. Is this right?

Also, what is the equivalence relation used to quotient $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ into $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: I would say that's about right. And of course the same holds of $\mathbb{N}$ itself: we chose sets with nice properties to let us define its algebra in the first place, even though we can do the same trick and make any countable set look like $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: And the equivalence relation I was referring to is $\langle n,m \rangle\sim\langle n',m' \rangle$ iff there's a $p$ such that $\langle n,m\rangle = \langle n'+p, m'+p\rangle$ or vice versa. The idea is that each pair refers to the unique integer equal to $n-m$, so we "identify" all the pairs of natural numbers with the same difference. If you think of it that way it's pretty easy to see how to define multiplication and addition.